# Determine if there is at least one zero in a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code: 
There exists a numpy array `multidimensional_array` which has either has all integers and no zeros, or one zero among many integers:

```
zeros_list = []   

for line in multidimensional_array:   # if find any zeros, append to list 'zeros'
    for x in line:
        if x.any() == 0:
            zeros_list.append(x)
        else:
            pass

for item in zeros:
    if item == 0:
        sys.stdout.write( 'True')   # if there is a zero, True
    else:
        sys.stdout.write( 'False')  # otherwise, False
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't run correctly. If there's a zero, it outputs `True`. If not, nothing happens. Each time I run this within a python script `script.py`, it should reset. How can I set this to run 'False'?

Comment: are you comparing string `'0'` with integer `0` ?

Comment: Your code is confusing, your problem statement is even more confusing and your variable names are supremely confusing (line in string1?). Please provide a minimum example of the desired input and output.

Comment: @timgeb I was foolishly trying to "simplify" the problem.

Comment: Strings don't have an `any` attribute, do they?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang what are you actually trying to do? Find out whether there is a zero in any string in a list of strings?

Comment: I am sorry. It is a numpy array. Is there or is there not *one* zero in a numpy array? That's the test

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, if `zeros` is an empty list, the `for` loop will be skipped over. You should just use an `if` as I did in my answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I am sorry. It is a [multidimensional] numpy array. Is there or is there not one zero in a numpy array? That's the test

Alright, that will get us someplace. You can simply issue

```
0 in multidimensional_array
```

Demo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> test1 = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> test1
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> 0 in test1
True
>>> test1[0][0] = 42
>>> test1
array([[42,  1,  2],
   [ 3,  4,  5]])
>>> 0 in test1
False
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> (A==0).any()
False
>>> (A!=0).all()
True
>>> 0 not in A
True
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,0,9]])
>>> (A==0).any()
True
>>> (A!=0).all()
False
>>> 0 not in A
False
```

Your final `for` loop should just be an `if`

```
if zeros:
    sys.stdout.write('True')   # if there is a zero, True
else:
    sys.stdout.write('False')  # otherwise, False
```

Comment: `(A==0).any()` should be the preferred option, as I will return on the first 0, rather than `.all()` which must scan the whole array.

Comment: @Benjamin, `.all` will also stop at the first `0` But I think either of those expressions will completely create the `(A==0)` array which the `in` version won't need to do.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy, yes, indeed, my mistake. I was thinking of a different case and jumped to conclusions.

Answer (score 3):

Since you said s is a string, a MUCH easier wasy would be to use [`string.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count)

```
>>> s = '112312390'
>>> s.count('0')
1
>>> s = '11231239'
>>> s.count('0')
0
>>>
```

Comment: Actually `string1` is a large numpy array---I just wanted to simplify things somewhat

Comment: Compared to your way, this is much cleaner, easier, faster.

Answer (score 0):

To add

```
import sys
zeros_list = []
string1 = input() #If you received the string this way, below code is valid. 

for line in string1:   # if find any zeros, append to list 'zeros'
    for x in line:
        if x == '0':#Here you should not check for digits when ciphering a string. Unless you put int(item) which could cause a TypeError
            zeros_list.append(x)
        else:
            pass

for item in zeros_list:
    if item == '0': #Here you should not check for digits when ciphering a string. Unless you put int(item) which could cause a TypeError
        sys.stdout.write( 'True')   # if there is a zero, True
    else:
        sys.stdout.write( 'False')  # otherwise, False`
```

And:

```
for item in zeros: #Did you mean zeros_list?
```

<strike>End note, **any()** is not a builtin Python function, where did this come about? Please include all the code necessary to run your code.</strike>

I stand corrected, any() is a [useful function](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#any) :D

---

**Just so you know,** 0 in Python as a boolean is False.

```
    if item == 0:
```

In the second for loop could have a different outcome than what you are expecting.

Comment: actually, `any` is a builtin python function, it's just not an attribute of `str`.

Answer (score -1):

If you append zeros_list then is should be:

```
for item in zeros_list:
```