# run while loop while a boolean condition is true

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop, boolean-expression

I have a 2D numpy array (400x400) and while there are zeros in this array I want to run a while loop until after a few iterations they are all removed. So in the while block I remove some of the zeros in every iteration. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278268/determine-if-there-is-at-least-one-zero-in-a-multidimensional-numpy-array) I have the code snipped to check if there are still zeros in my array:

```
check = 0 in array
```

This returns either a 'True' or a 'False' and is working. Now I want to use this in the beginning of the while-loop and I expected it to work like the following:

```
while 0 in array == True:
    'do sth.'
```

Instead I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I can make a workaround where in the end of every while-loop I write the result of 'check = 0 in array' into another variable and check this variable in the beginning of the while loop, but I think there should be a better way.

Comment: Why did you append the `== True` to the condition?

Comment: I've no idea, but now I got it. Thank you.

Comment: You mentioned that your array is 2D, the condition is checking if an array is equal to 0. That’s why it’s ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python parses this as

```
while 0 in (array==True):
```

where of course you mean

```
while (0 in array) == True:
```

which however of course is better written

```
while 0 in array:
```

Python's flow-control conditionals already implicitly convert every expression into a "truthiness" value which is either `True` or `False`. See further [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, this is want you want:

```
array = [[20,0],[11, 1]]
count = 0 
while count < len(array): 
    if 0 in array[count]: 
        print("Found zero")
    count += 1
```

Output:

```
[20, 0]
Found zero
[11, 1]
```

Comment: In my case it is not important to count the zeros. The aim was to keep the while loop going as long as there are zeros in the array. Then in the loop these zeros are removed in several iteration steps.

Comment: My code snippet is not counting the zeros. The `count` variable ensures that the loop is running until the end (stop-condition). The `print` statement is a placeholder for whatever you want to do with the current array element (sublist). If you don't want to use a `count` variable you also implement this as a nested `for` loop.